# What is correct query for obtaining the below information

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
#id | title | series | series_position | author | img_url | object_key | e_tag | page_number
```

Given I have the above table column, what would be the correct query to obtain the following data order from a single query:

```
[author1:{
    [series1:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]],
    [series2:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]],
    [series3:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]]]
},
author2:{
    [series1:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]],
    [series2:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]],
    [series3:[{title:title1,series_position:1},{title:title2,series_position:2},{title:title3,series_position:3}]]]
}]
```

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
books = Books.query.order_by(Books.author).all()
authors = sorted(set(book.author for book in books))
```

After which I do something like the below pseudo code to display the data in jinja:

```
{%for author is authors%}:
<div id={{author}}>
    for book in books
        if author in book.author:
            <li><a>book.title,book.series,book.series_position</a></li>
</div>

{%endfor%}
```

Below is the image of what the above jinja code currently generates frontend
[image: enter image shere]
Below is the image of the table:

[image]

Comment: The list (example below) is not correct, maybe you want a dictionary?

[author1:{ [series1:

Comment: Its a pseudo list/dictionary .. the data type is not the important part at the moment as much as the data structure/order @archer

Comment: ok so you want some sql query to pull all the data at once, or any python code that does the work is ok?

Comment: sql query/python code is fine. Its not "pull all that data" , its more all along the lines of pull  all that data whilst maintaining the above structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the data structure you want ( in a dictionary format):

```
import pandas as pd
conn=... #your sql connection to your database here
df=pd.read_sql('select * from Books', conn)
d={}
for i in set(df.author):
    d[i]={}
    df2=df[df.author==i]
    for k in set(df2.series):
        d[i][k]=[]
        df3=df2[df2.series==k]
        for j in range(len(df3)):
            d[i][k].append({'title':df3['title'].iloc[j], 'series_position':df3['series_position'].iloc[j]})
```

Comment: the above code does not work. That is what the downvote is for. Although the above code does kinda give me an idea in which direction to explore working on. For that. Thanks! @archer

Comment: I have made some changes, please check it again

Comment: Thank you for trying again, however at the moment I cant fully investigate it. Here is the error message that results from your code.

  File "C:\Users\akibr\Desktop\PythonPractice\posGresSql\app\routes.py", line 22, in index
    for i in set(df.author):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: Yeah, sorry my mistake. I added some lines at the beggining, it should work now

Comment: Thanks ! @archer